# MS Word Make includetext field into straight text

Tags: microsoft-word, embedded-fonts

simple question. I've used the includetext field in an MS Word text. How can I convert that into just straight text, not embedded text? Word is wetting its pants in fear when I try to do a straight copy-and-paste over the includetext field by erasing or imposing formatting or fonts from one doc or another. I just want to convert that text, as it's formatted, into straight text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, everyone. The trick is Ctrl+Shift+F9.

*sigh* Search high and low on Google for an answer, find nothing. Post it here, give Google one more shot, and there's your answer.

Thanks to Allen Wyatt at Tips.net for the quick fix. https://word.tips.net/T001035_Converting_Field_Results_to_Text.html